# What is the proper syntax to combine text with HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# foreach loop with the following:

```
lblCheckedNodes.Text += node.Text + "&#x25BA< br />";
```

That displays like this: myCheckedNodeText►< br /> .  Which shows the line break characters instead of actually doing the line break, but if I do:

```
lblCheckedNodes.Text += node.Text + "<br />";
```

the line return works, but i can't seem to get both working.

Comment: Side note: if you have many of those _...Text += ...Text_  I suggest to use a StringBuilder instead

Comment: @Steve or if you have it inside a loop (which is the case :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing a semicolon.
Try this

```
lblCheckedNodes.Text += node.Text + "&#x25BA;<br />";
```

Comment: I tried many different combinations, some with the semicolon and some without and never got it to work.  I copy/pasted your answer and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Missing Semicolon in HTML Entity**

HTML entities like `&#x25BA` require a trailing semicolon to indicate the end of the entity itself, so you need to ensure that is present:

```
lblCheckedNodes.Text += node.Text + "&#x25BA;<br />";
```

**Consider a StringBuilder**

As mentioned in the comments, if you are continually concatenating strings together, you may be better off using the `StringBuilder` class, which is far more efficient at handling that type of activity:

```
StringBuilder nodes = new StringBuilder("");
// Build your strings here
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
     // You have a few options for concatenation here
     // Basic Concatenation -> nodes.Append(node.Text + " &#x25BA; <br />");
     // String.Format() -> nodes.Append(String.Format("{0} &#x25BA; <br />", node.Text));
     // String Iterpolation (seen below)
     nodes.Append($"{node.Text} &#x25BA; <br />");
}
// Set your label content
lblCheckedNodes.Text = nodes.ToString();
```

Comment: using String Interpolation sounds better :) alothough OP might not have C# 6 yet

Comment: I've added examples using normal concatenation, `String.Format()` and string interpolation, which should cover most scenarios.